# Structured data in Webmaster Tools

Tags: google-search-console

I have an eCommerce site. In Webmaster Tools its showing:

> We do not detect any structured data on your site.
>   Structured data helps Google understand the content on your site, which can be used to display rich snippets in search results.

I don't know much about this message in Webmaster Tools. My site contains products, categories and manufacturers. What do I need to do to provide structured data?  How does it help?

I already read about schema.org for products (our site contains 200 products). How can I get rich snippets?

Comment: For product they gave Structured data. Already i read that post.If i want to give structured data for my website for which content i have to give

Comment: Everything you need to know about structured data and rich snippets is way to much information to fit in an answer on this website.   Please narrow this question down to on particular aspect that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 2):

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/3069489?hl=en
Structured Data Markup Helper shows you how to update your site so that Google—and potentially other companies' products—can understand the data it contains. Once Google understands the data on your site, your data can be presented more attractively and in new ways. In addition if you send HTML-formatted email to your customers, Markup Helper can show you how to change your email templates so GMail can present the data in your email in new and useful ways.

Try this https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-helper/u/0/

[image]

You simply need to highlight and tag the data. It will automatically create Microdata you may also get JSON output

Following is the example screen shot of HTML generated by this tool.